# Kill an app when a CheckBox is checked

Tags: android, checkbox

My code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);

    ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
    this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    int i=0;

    // get a reference for the TableLayout
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);

    TextView[] tx = new TextView[procInfos.size()];
    TableRow[] row = new TableRow[procInfos.size()];
    CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[procInfos.size()];


    for(i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {         
        // create a new TableRow
        row[i] = new TableRow(this);

        //Styl
        row[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);

        // create a new TextView
        tx[i] = new TextView(this);

        //Styl
        tx[i].setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.normalText);

        // set the text to "text xx"   
        tx[i].setText("     "+ procInfos.get(i).processName +"\n");

        // create a CheckBox
        cb[i] = new CheckBox(this);

        // add the TextView and the CheckBox to the new TableRow
        row[i].addView(tx[i]);
        row[i].addView(cb[i]);

        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        table.addView(row[i]);
    }

}

public void buttonClicked(View button) {
    ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
    this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    // get a reference for the TableLayout
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);

    TextView[] tx = new TextView[procInfos.size()];
    TableRow[] row = new TableRow[procInfos.size()];
    CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[procInfos.size()];

    table.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) { 
         // create a new TableRow
        row[i] = new TableRow(this);

        //Styl
        row[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);

        // create a new TextView
        tx[i] = new TextView(this);

        //Styl
        tx[i].setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.normalText);

        // set the text to "text xx"   
        tx[i].setText("     "+ procInfos.get(i).processName +"\n");

        // create a CheckBox
        cb[i] = new CheckBox(this);         

        // add the TextView and the CheckBox to the new TableRow
        row[i].addView(tx[i]);
        row[i].addView(cb[i]);

        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        table.addView(row[i]);

        if (((CheckBox) cb[i]).isChecked()) {
            int pid=procInfos.get(i).processName.length();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                       "Chx " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

    }
}
```

I have a CheckBox array, 1 for each table row.
I am trying to kill the selected app if the CheckBox is checked, but if I select any CheckBox and press the kill Button, nothing happens.

Thanks for your help, I am an android beginner.

Comment: The kernel is probably not allowing you to kill those processes, because they do not belong to your application/package. See [`killProcess`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess(int)).

Comment: You are trying to kill an App or just a Process?

Comment: I can't see where do you assign buttonClicked.

Comment: I am trying to kill process which i selected with checkbox

Answer (score 3):

You can't kill an app if it doesn't have the same userid has yours unless your phone is rooted and your application has the root privileges.

Answer (score 2):

the method `killProcess` won't work if you'll try to call it for process ID that is not your own application, or process that started by your application. all that mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29)

that's basic security limitation.  if you could kill from your application every application you desired - it was very problematic security issue - apps could kill each other without user interaction...

Comment: Ty for your answer, but Toast also does not work, i have no idea why

Comment: @user3306867: I don't see any place buttonClicked method is called, debug your app, maybe the method never been called

Comment: he probably declared it on the layout file.

Comment: Yes, I also think so, but we have no evidence... that's why I pointed it out. Maybe he just forgot to set it, so no event fires.

Comment: yes i have declared it on the layout file, android:onClick="buttonClicked"

Comment: @user3306867: debug this method(put breakpoint) to check if it called when you click the button.  anyway - you can forget about killing process of other apps

Comment: i check it, method is called but Toast does not work . And how work others task killers ?